# Как узнать на какой строке echo

Tags: php, echo

в wp с помощью ajax получаю данные из function.php но в месте с данными выводится какой-то 0. Вот мне нужно узнать откуда этот 0 берется. Как найти это злое echo.

P.S.через другой аякс этот ноль не выводится.

Comment: Дебагать свой код построчно. Или телепатов можете подождать.

Comment: @u_mulder Да знать бы как.

Comment: Комментируете все строки и начинаете раскомменчивать по одной.

Comment: @u_mulder Знаем мы эту фишку. Ток php на 1800 строк. Как думаете скок это займет?

Comment: Других методов пока не завезли.

Comment: @makcim512 пфф. всего 1800? да у меня в проекте один маленький файлик в 5к строк и ничего, ориентируемся. 1800 строк поблочно раскоментировать - минуты 3-4

Comment: `через другой аякс этот ноль не выводится.` - а что это значит?

Comment: @Сергей Мишин Значит то что при ajax запросе к только к другой функции этот 0 не возвращается.

Comment: @makcim512 напиши в вопросе функции в файле `function.php` к которым идет обращение по ajax и покажи конкретно ту, которая выдает 0.

Answer (score -2):

В конце функции к которой мы обращались по ajax нужно поставить die(); И ноль не выводится.

Comment: Не силен в WP, но обычно после выполнения AJAX запросов идет закрытие подключения к БД, возможно даже какие-то задачи по крон проверяются. Возможно этот вариант нужно рассмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178884/4822490

Comment: заметать грязь под ковёр и называть это уборкой :)